# How can I convert sheep's wool into bags?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I go to Clothier's Shop and ask to *Construct yarn Bag*.
It says: *Needs 1 unused yarn cloth*.
I go to Loom and ask to *Weave Cloth (Wool/Hair Yarn)*.
It says: *Needs 1 unused collected yarn thread*.

But I already have it!

[image]

I'm playing version 0.40.16.

Answer (score 2):

The basics to double check:

- Burrows (can your crafters reach the wool?)
- Shop Permissions (can the shop use any quality item?)
- Stockpile Permissions (can the stockpile be used by that shop/any shop?)

IIRC, some "wool" is actually hair gotten from butchering, and not from shearing. This type of thread can only be used by a hospital for suturing.

Try making a stockpile that only takes wool yarn (in bins) and only gives to the Loom. Make a second stockpile that only takes wool cloth and only gives to the Clothier's Shop. From scratch, shear the sheep and watch the wool be moved from the Farmer's Workshop to the pile, etc. If you can make a bag from that, but only from that then it's likely the result of butcher-hair. If you can move these items to the new stockpile in the first place then they may be forbidden or you have no idle dwarves with the correct labors enabled.

Comment: I have no burrows. I didn't set *Shop Permissions* since I don't even know how to ..) On screenshot you can see, that I've sheared sheeps -- already have 6 wool yarn currently in game. And none of them are forbidden.

Comment: Oh, the problem was in that the stockpile, that had yarn, was allowed to move things only to specific workshop. Thanks!

Comment: Also another possible reason is probably when `wool yarn` is in Forbidden container.